# Image Contrast Enhancement Using Statistical Methods

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I am Implementing Image Contrast Enhancement Using Statistical Methods as described in this [research paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214317318301562#b0095). 
After Applying Weibull Density Function, I found the values of w for the V plane. I then applied the Transformation function all as described. Although the final result which I am getting is not convincing.

Here is an image before and after the transformation - [image: Original Image]
[image: Image After Transformation]

These results do not seem to be correct to me.

Here is the code snippet -

```
def Weibull(x, a, b):
    w = (b/a)*((x/a)**(b-1))
    exponential = (x/a)**b
    w = w * np.exp(-exponential)
    print("Shape = ", w.shape)
    return w
def intensityTransformation(w, Skewness):
    mean = w.mean()
    for i in range(w.shape[0]):
        for j in range(w.shape[1]):
            if(w[i][j]<mean and Skewness>0):
                w[i][j] = mean
            elif(w[i][j]>mean and Skewness<0):
                w[i][j] = mean
            else:
                w[i][j] = w[i][j]
    return w
```